# Installing Newly Published Oauth2 based Google Marketplace App

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

On the process of migrating from OpenId based login to Oauth2 based login of Google Marketplace App SSO, we built an Oauth2 based app & we opensourced our gapps oauth2 app 
( https://github.com/Aplopio/django_gapps_oauth2_login )

We published our OAuth2 Login based app to users with a specific domain name account or people with the link.

But we faced some issues while installing:

- After agreeing to install on the entire domain, the pop-up did not get closed.
- The Get Ready to Install, on clicking Continue again opened the same pop-up.
- By closing the pop-up, I was redirected to my app, performing the Oauth2 Login authentication.

Has anyone faced this issue? If so how did you resolve it?

Please update if it's a known issue while installing new google marketplace app.

Comment: What browser and OS were you using when you saw the issue?

Comment: Ubuntu & Google Chrome & same in Chromium browser too

Comment: Not able to repro on any browser - but can you try Firefox?

Comment: Yes tried in Firefox, same issue. Also tried in Mac with Google Chrome browser.
Btw, here is the app link: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recruiterbox-v2/efbcldkjnachkdjfjmpialepnejdaihm
Please let me know if you are able to install, without having to close the pop-up.
Please Let me know if something is wrong in our end.

Comment: @jonathanberi Any update on the issue? By the way, I was able to install in Firefox without any issues. Is this is a known bug in Google Chrome? Can I publish my app in this state? Please reply all. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed that it is a chrome only issue. They fix should go out Thursday or Monday pst.